# best way to implement a deck for a card game in python

Tags: python

What is the best way to store the cards and suits in python so that I can hold a reference to these values in another variable?

For example, if I have a list called hand (cards in players hand), how could I hold values that could refer to the names of suits and values of specific cards, and how would these names and values of suits and cards be stored?

Comment: You can certainly represent a card using simple tuples or encoded strings, but Ned Batchelder's answer gives you more capabilities.  If you start with a simple card game like War before taking on something more complicated like Poker, you'll see the value of defining a Card class, where you can define rich comparison operators, making it easier to compare an ace versus a '10' using class methods, instead of creating some funky specialized logic trying to compare "A" for ace vs. "T" for 10.  Note also that some games have multiple possible values to cards, like the ace in 21 can be 1 or 11.

Answer (score 26):

Poker servers tend to use a 2-character string to identify each card, which is nice because it's easy to deal with programmatically and just as easy to read for a human.

```
>>> import random
>>> import itertools
>>> SUITS = 'cdhs'
>>> RANKS = '23456789TJQKA'
>>> DECK = tuple(''.join(card) for card in itertools.product(RANKS, SUITS))
>>> hand = random.sample(DECK, 5)
>>> print hand
['Kh', 'Kc', '6c', '7d', '3d']
```

**Edit**: This is actually straight from a poker module I wrote to evaluate poker hands, you can see more here: http://pastebin.com/mzNmCdV5

Comment: For what it's worth, instead of using tuples for SUITS and RANKS, you can just use strings: SUITS = 'cdhs' and RANKS = '23456789TJQKA'.

Comment: Note that the cards do not get taken from the deck in this example, meaning that the next player could get dealt the same card. A more realistic implementation would have the DECK be a list, from which random cards get "popped" doing `DECK.pop(r)`

Comment: Can someone please explain what each step of constructing the "DECK" is doing in more detail? Thanks

Answer (score 7):

The simplest thing would be to use a list of tuples, where the cards are ints and the suits are strings:

```
hand = [(1, 'spade'), (10, 'club'), ...]
```

But simplest may not be what you want.  Maybe you want a class to represent a card:

```
class Card:
    def __init__(self, rank, suit):
        self.rank = rank
        self.suit = suit

    def __repr__(self):
        letters = {1:'A', 11:'J', 12:'Q', 13:'K'}
        letter = letters.get(self.rank, str(self.rank))
        return "<Card %s %s>" % (letter, self.suit)

hand = [Card(1, 'spade'), Card(10, 'club')]
```

Answer (score 2):

A deck of cards is comprised of the same range of values (1 - 13) in each of *four* suits, which suggests a *Cartesian product*. List comprehension is an elegant, dense syntax for doing this:

```
values = range(1, 10) + "Jack Queen King".split()
suits = "Diamonds Clubs Hearts Spades".split()

deck_of_cards = ["%s of %s" % (v, s) for v in values for s in suits]
```

*in python 3*:

```
deck_of_cards = ["{0} of {1}".format(v, s) for v in values for s in suits]
```

That's how they are when you take a brand new deck out of the box; to play you need to shuffle them:

```
from random import shuffle

shuffle(deck_of_cards)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use a number, and decide on a mapping between number and "card". For example:

number MOD 13 = face value (after a +1)

number DIV 13 = suit

Comment: It should be noted that you'd use values from 0 to 51 for this method for each card. Then you could assign each suit a number from 0 to 3.

Answer (score 1):

```
import collections

C, H, D, S = "CLUBS", "HEARTS", "DICE", "SPADE"
Card = collections.namedtuple("Card", "suit value")

hand = []

hand.append(Card(C, 3))
hand.append(Card(H, "A"))
hand.append(Card(D, 10))
hand.append(Card(S, "Q"))

for card in hand:
    print(card.value, card.suit)
```