# In Python how do I assign an integer to an element in a list that contains strings?

Tags: python, list

```
    ## made a list of playing cards e.g. 2C 2 of Clubs and QS is queen of Spades
    num=0
    numberlist=[]
    newSuitList= []
    for i in range(8):
        num = 2
        num = num + i
        num = str(num) + 'C'
        numberlist.append(num)
    for i in range (5):
        suitList = ["T", "J", "Q", "K", "A"]
        suit = suitList[i] + 'C'
        newSuitList.append(suit)
    wholeDeck = numberlist+newSuitList
```

after making the deck, i would like to assign each card a value so
 that the King of Spades(with value 13) would have a higher value than 
the Queen of Spades(12), for example. I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: You are looking for dict instead of list.

Comment: You may wish to look at these ways to represent playing cards in Python - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518753/best-way-to-implement-a-deck-for-a-card-game-in-python

Comment: I didn't realise that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since your goal is to associate a card with a value, you want to use a dictionary instead (like the comment says). Here is an implementation that does not change your code alot that could help you:

```
num=0
wholeDeck = {}
for i in range(8):
    num = 2
    num +=  i
    wholeDeck[str(num)+'C']  = num
suitList = ["T", "J", "Q", "K", "A"]
for item in suitList:
    num +=1
    wholeDeck[item+'C']  = num
```

You can, therefore, access a card like so,

```
print(wholeDeck['KC']) --> returns 13
```

Comment: is this possible without using a dict? Teacher doesn't want us using dicts for now..

Comment: Look at answer above

Answer (score 0):

Another simple way to would be using a list:

```
cards = ['A', 2, 3 , 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'J', 'Q', 'K']

def getCardValue(card):
  return cards.index(card) + 1
```

Then `getCardvalue('Q')` would return the value `12`